# Unique integer from array on each refresh (from previous) using $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I'm needing the user to always get a unique integer than from what previous returned on last refresh of the browser.

```
$count = count($page->images) - 1;
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {

    $randomIndex = rand(0, $count);

    if ($session->get("randomImage") && $session->get("randomImage") == $randomIndex) {
        $i = 0;
        continue;
    }
}
$session->set("randomImage", $randomIndex);
```

However I'm still sometimes getting the same integer twice in a row.

$session is part of the ProcessWire API but is essentially the same as `$_SESSION`.

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong? I think instead of 'continue' it needs to reset the loop again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop,

```
$last = $session->get("randomImage");
$rng = random_int(0, count($page->images) - 1); // < PHP 7? Use rand()

while ($rng === $last) {
    $rng = random_int(0, count($page->images) - 1);    
}

$session->set("randomImage", $rng);
```

This loop will keep attempting to generate a random number until the new one does not equal to the old one. If you are worried about being stuck in a loop forever then you could keep a counter and break out after certain number of iterations.

Comment: Feel free to explain your down-vote so I can improve my answer.

Comment: @user234461 Two things: 1. That's not a requirement but fair enough. 2. Have you seen the state of your answer?

Comment: It's kind of important since not only does it build understanding, more importantly it weeds out questioners who have misdiagnosed their problem. I challenge you to explain why OP's code is doing what s/he claims it is. And what's wrong with my answer? It answers the question perfectly.

Comment: Also using a `while` loop and making multiple attempts is entirely unnecessary, see my other answer.#

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know why you're not getting unique integers since the code looks like it should work, but here's an alternative approach that's a bit simpler.

```
$randomOffset = rand(1,$count-1) ;
$session->set(
    "randomImage" ,
    ($session->get("randomImage") + $randomOffset) % $count
) ;
```

`%`, is the modulo operator, so we're doing clock-face arithmetic on a 'clock' with $count "hours". The offset is constrained to be less than a full 'rotation', so we can never get back to the same 'hour' on the 'clock', but we can get to every other hour with a uniformly random chance of each.

I suspect your problem might be somewhere else in your codebase, however.

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
$count = count($page ->images) - 1   ;
for ($i=0;  $i<$count                ;$i++){

    $randomIndex = rand(0, $count)   ;

    if ($session->get("randomImage")
    &&  $session->get("randomImage")
    ==                $randomIndex)        {
        $i = 0                       ;
        if($i==0){continue           ;     }
    }
}
$session->set("randomImage",
                        $randomIndex);
```